# Django redis cache crsf token dont change

Tags: python, django, caching, redis

I try to redis cache but csrf tokens dont work now they do not change. The same csrf token always appears as the cache.

my form like this;

```
<form action="{% url "set_language" %}" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
    <select style="border-radius: 5px;padding: 5px;"name="language" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    {% for language in languages %}
    <option value="{{ language.code }}"
        {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>
        {{ language.name_local }}
    </option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
</form>
```

how can i disable cache only csrf tokens?

thanks.

Comment: see this link if you want to disable cache from specific view: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715473/1033510

Comment: @shotgunner thanks for answer. but never cache is canceling all over the page. i want to disable cache only "change language form".